# I want to show multiple location from json/ api using Android current version

Tags: android

I want to show multiple location from json or api using Android.

I trying to create but getMap() cannot support in previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in XML.

```
 <fragment
           android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And try to use this in Java file

```
private GoogleMap map;
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
// Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
// map.
if (map == null) {

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location loc) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Use this method to create multiple marker from API.

```
protected void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, Bitmap iconResID) {

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                   /* .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_client_org))*/
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconResID)));
                   /* .title(title)
                   .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .snippet(snippet)*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks.   But . .. Still error this line:  cannot resolve method getMap()      map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();